# EntityFramework 5 - Conflicting changes to the role 'x' of the relationship 'x' have been detected

Tags: c#, entity-framework, entity-framework-5

I have this model (Animal Model):

```
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public int AnimalSpecieId { get; set; }
    public int AnimalBreedId { get; set; }
    public Nullable<int> ProtectorId { get; set; }
    public Nullable<int> OwnerId { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public virtual Owner Owner { get; set; }
    public virtual Protector Protector { get; set; }
```

Protector Model:

```
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Address { get; set; }
    public string Phone { get; set; }
    public string CellPhone { get; set; }
    public string Email { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Animal> Animals { get; set; }
```

Owner Model:

```
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Address { get; set; }
    public string Phone { get; set; }
    public string CellPhone { get; set; }
    public string Email { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Animal> Animals { get; set; }
```

When I insert this model at the first time, if

> ProtectorID = 1

and

> OwnerID = null

it's ok, but, and I try to update this model, changing to:

> OwnerID = 1

and

> ProtectorID = null

I get the error in title, someone can help me with that ?

Comment: Can you post the Protector and Owner entity as well? Usually this error occurs when there is a property referring back to the (in this case) Animal model. Also make sure an Owner with ID 1 exists.

Comment: Updated with Protector and Owner models.

Comment: I am blank for the moment.. :|

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found the problem, after read this [msdn post](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/5fa9dbb9-9b4a-43dc-bfa0-e1680d8f6ed0/conflicting-changes-to-the-roleof-the-relationshiphave-been-detected?forum=adonetefx), I was thinking and found out what was happening, in my repository when I will update my entity, I was forgeting to set null all the related entities.

Old code:

```
var oldAnimal = context.Animals.Find(animal.Id);

if (oldAnimal != null)
{
    oldAnimal.AnimalBreed = context.AnimalBreeds.Find(animal.AnimalBreed.Id);
    oldAnimal.AnimalSpecie = context.AnimalSpecies.Find(animal.AnimalSpecie.Id);

    oldAnimal.OwnerId = animal.OwnerId;
    oldAnimal.ProtectorId = animal.ProtectorId;
    oldAnimal.Castrated = animal.Castrated;
    oldAnimal.DateBirth = animal.DateBirth;
    oldAnimal.Gender = animal.Gender;
    oldAnimal.Name = animal.Name;
    oldAnimal.UpdateDate = DateTime.Now;
    oldAnimal.Vaccinated = animal.Vaccinated;
    oldAnimal.Weight = animal.Weight;
}

context.SaveChanges();

return animal;
```

new code:

```
var oldAnimal = context.Animals.Find(animal.Id);

if (oldAnimal != null)
{
    oldAnimal.AnimalBreed = context.AnimalBreeds.Find(animal.AnimalBreed.Id);
    oldAnimal.AnimalSpecie = context.AnimalSpecies.Find(animal.AnimalSpecie.Id);
    oldAnimal.Owner = null;
    oldAnimal.Protector = null;

    oldAnimal.OwnerId = animal.OwnerId;
    oldAnimal.ProtectorId = animal.ProtectorId;
    oldAnimal.Castrated = animal.Castrated;
    oldAnimal.DateBirth = animal.DateBirth;
    oldAnimal.Gender = animal.Gender;
    oldAnimal.Name = animal.Name;
    oldAnimal.UpdateDate = DateTime.Now;
    oldAnimal.Vaccinated = animal.Vaccinated;
    oldAnimal.Weight = animal.Weight;
}

context.SaveChanges();

return animal;
```

Comment: This worked for me too. But what if I want to maintain that circular dependency ? i.e., i want oldAnimal.Owner to be set back to animal.Owner ?? I have this kind of requirement. In next steps, i will be accessing oldAnimal's owner as owner object itself. If i set it to null, i cannot access it. Any hints ? Let me know.

Answer (score 5):

I don't agree with the above answer. I am not sure whether it solved your problem permanently because the issue is not related with the null value assignment. The actual reason is related with `DBContext`. When we go for any `SaveChanges` the context needs to be dispatched properly in order to proceed with the next `SaveChanges` to insert another record into DB on the same item with a different foreign key. You just need to add the below line after your "`context.SaveChanges()`"

```
context.Entry(your object).State = System.Data.Entity.EntityState.Detached;
```

This will solve the conflicts. Multiple insertion with same context results in conflicts.

Apologize if my comments criticised your answer in any manner.

Comment: What happens is that I have only one context, one `Entity`, it's `Animal Entity`, with many `foreign keys` associated to it, only way, that I found up to now, it's make the `Entity` associated `null` and updating the `foreign entity` `ID`, in the `Animal Entity`, with the real ID, in this case `Entity Framework` can update without inserting a new entity.

Comment: But thanks anyway, and you don't criticised in any way my answer... It's just your answer can't be applied in my problem.