# Conflicting changes to the role x of the relationship y have been detected in web.api

Tags: c#, entity-framework, asp.net-web-api

I realize there are a couple of similar questions (example [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19408041/entityframework-5-conflicting-changes-to-the-role-x-of-the-relationship-x) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11939964/conflicting-changes-to-the-role-x-of-the-relationship-y-have-been-detected)) but I don't seem to be able to apply their solution to my specific problem.

I have these classes:

**Profile**

```
public class ProfileModel
{
    public ProfileModel()
    {
        Resources = new List<OptionsModel>();
    }
    [Key]
    public  int BID { get; set; }
    public string Update_date { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }
    public byte[] Picture_file { get; set; }
    public string Contact { get; set; }

    public ICollection<OptionsModel> Resources { get; set; }
    public virtual MissionModel Mission { get; set; }

}
```

**Mission Model**

```
 public class MissionModel
    {
     [ForeignKey("Business")]
     public int MissionModelId { get; set; }
          ....more properties...
     public virtual ProfileModel Business { get; set; }
    }
```

And **Resource**

```
   public class OptionsModel
    {
        [Key]
        public int Resource_Id{ get; set; }
        public string Resource_name { get; set; }
        public string Resource_description { get; set; }

        //profile
        public virtual ProfileModel Business { get; set; }

        //all other config
        public virtual AccessModel Access { get; set; }
        public virtual GoalModel Goal { get; set; }
        public virtual MissionModel Mission { get; set; }
        public virtual SettingModel Setting { get; set; }
    }
```

It's a Web API application and when I make a post using Json, I get the following error:

> "ExceptionMessage": "Conflicting changes to the role 'MissionModel_Business_Target' of the relationship 'filament.Models.MissionModel_Business' have been detected.",

From the second link I referenced above, it seems like it is trying to create mission model but the same model appears to be different. I have tried a handful of things, but nothing seems to work well enough. For example, when I remove the navigational properties on one end of the realtionship, it works (as in, it saves the data to the db) but the data is not organized properly as expected.

Any help is greatly appereicated!

Comment: Showing the model code is a good start. We would also need to see the simplified code of how you're adding these to the context and ultimately saving them

Comment: @CallumLinington it's a simple controller generated by Visual Studio. It takes a ProfileModel as an argument, validates it, adds to the context, and saves changes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The second link helped me solve the problem. I just set the references within the objects to null and entity properly maps them afterwards. In my case this looked like this:

```
foreach(var a in profileModel.Resources)
            {
                a.Business = null;
                a.Access.Resource = null;
                a.Goal.Resource = null;
                a.Setting.Resource = null;

            }

            profileModel.Mission.Business=null;
```

I'm not sure if this is the right way of doing it, but it works.